# Windows elevated user rights for limited time

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, login, windows-server-2003, administrator

I have a task which includes adding an user(s) to local Administrator group and Remote Desktop group in Windows 2003 or Windows 2008 servers. However I have to grant these rights for alimited time, for example until tomorrow morning, or for an hour. So I have to do it manually, and some times I forget to remove the added user from groups.

Is there any program which manages this automatically?

I mean I need a software where I can set time limit for membership of a certain group. This will solve my problem.

Thanks
Sail

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Write a script that will execute at a scheduled time using a scheduled task that will change the group privileges.
2. You can disable the account at a set date (it's not exactly what you asked for but it does keep the user from connecting after a set date). This is done by setting the expiration date for the user. However, I think this option is only available if you are on a domain. (I don't have a non domain computer to test this with right now.)

[image]

Note that if you are giving the users `Administrator` privileges they can undo what ever you set up as they have exactly the same rights as you. Why do the users temporarily need to be administrator?

Comment: 1. What script language does support this kind of change of group membership?

Comment: 2. The exact description of our enviroment is the Windows domain. The mentioned users are developers and time to time they need to update/upgrade their softwares. These softwares are installed on windows 2003/2008 servers so that is why I have to grant an admin and RDP rights. Your recommendation is not an option, because the users are not temporarly.